collect_set and size - on medium size data overrunning
I have a dataframe containing columns: device_id, country, language, channel, genre, and few others attributes . The data is partitioned by year, month, day and hour.
I need to determine the count of unique devices associated with each attribute. specifically the number of unique device_ids for country, language, channel, and genre separately like below as separate columns.
device_id | genre| genre_unique_devices | country | country_unique_devices | language | language_unique_devices | channel | channel_unique_devices

Hence performed computation using collect_set and size for single hour data.

Input hour partition data is ~30GB.
Using fairly decent cluster

worker - n2-standard-8 GCP VMs (3 node - each having 32GB memory, 8 core), so total 24 core and 96GB memory.
driver - n2-standard-4 (16GB memory,4 core)



However below query is overrunning and not completing.
 select device_id,
        genre,
        size(collect_set(device_id) over(partition by genre)) as genre_did_count,
        country,
        size(collect_set(device_id) over(partition by country)) as country_did_count,
        language,
        size(collect_set(device_id) over(partition by language)) as language_did_count,
        channel,
        size(collect_set(device_id) over(partition by channel)) as channel_name_did_count 
from input_dataframe
where year=2024 and month=07 and day=15 and hour=11

But if I run below query for single attribute, I get result in < 1 min.
 select device_id,
        genre,
        size(collect_set(device_id) over(partition by genre)) as genre_did_count
from input_dataframe
where year=2024 and month=07 and day=15 and hour=11

Question:

When using collect_set in Spark, does it utilize typical distributed parallel processing or does it consolidate all data onto a single executor, potentially causing overruns or job failures?

